# How to get to the 5th HTML Table in the DOM Using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom, html-table

I want to pull information out of the table.

How can I do this if jQuery does not offer a table selector?

Answer (score 3):

See the [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
var fifth = $('table:eq(4)'); // fifth table; first table is eq(0)
```

Alternatively, use the [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var fifth = $('table').eq(4); // fifth table; first table is eq(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using jQuery `eq` method which reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
$('table').eq(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does have a table selector:

```
$("table").eq(4).doSomething;
```